# Create SQL Server table error

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, create-table

I'm trying to create a new table with the results from a query. I'm working in SQL Server 2012

```
CREATE TABLE [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data] AS 
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[New Data]
    LEFT JOIN [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[OctMktSeg] ON [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[New Data].[Customer ID] = [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[OctMktSeg].[Account Number]
    LEFT JOIN [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[tblMktSeg&MPI] ON [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[New Data].[Customer ID] = [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[tblMktSeg&MPI].[Customer ID1]
    WHERE 
        (MKTSEG LIKE '%Repair%' OR MKTSEG LIKE 'Auto Glass' OR 
         MKTSEG LIKE 'IA - Individual' OR MKTSEG IS NULL)
        AND (MPI LIKE 'N' OR MPI IS NULL)
        AND [Item Category] LIKE '%Term'
        AND [Month] >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000')
    ;
```

It keeps telling me there's "Incorrect syntax" near the first open parentheses and I have no idea why. Thoughts?

Comment: Are there columns in the joined table that overlap in the query?

Comment: Does the select statement execute correctly on its own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that syntax is valid in SQL SERVER, Have you tried this before ?
This is valid syntax in order to create a new table:

```
SELECT 
-- SPECIFY THE NAME OF THE COLUMNS IN THE SELECT LIST, AVOID *
* 
--INSERT DATA INTO NEW TABLE
INTO [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[filtered_data]
from [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[New Data] t1
left join [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[OctMktSeg] t2 ON t1.[Customer ID] = t2.[Account Number]
left join [Service Contract Data].[dbo].[tblMktSeg&MPI] t3 on t1.[Customer ID] = t3.[Customer ID1]
WHERE (MKTSEG like '%Repair%' or MKTSEG like 'Auto Glass' or MKTSEG like 'IA - Individual' or MKTSEG is null)
    and (MPI like 'N' or MPI is null)
    and [Item Category] like '%Term'
    and [Month] >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing an open peren `(` right after your `WHERE`

```
WHERE ((MKTSEG like '%Repair%' or MKTSEG like 'Auto Glass' or MKTSEG like 'IA - Individual' or MKTSEG is null)
and (MPI like 'N' or MPI is null)
and [Item Category] like '%Term'
and [Month] >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

Comment: The query executes correctly on it's own so I don't think it's an issue with the select query